# Should all radioactive elements with HL smaller than 1000 years have 90% of their atoms already decayed on Earth?

Tags: radioactivity, elements, half-life

Should all radioactive elements with HL smaller than 1000 years have 90% of their atoms already decayed on Earth? If that kind of radioactive source is found today should almost all of its atoms be transmutated?

Answer (score 5):

If you find atoms of a radioactive element with half life smaller than 1000 years, you can be pretty confident that they weren't formed along with the Earth (since over 4 billion years practically 100% will have decayed). That doesn't mean such elements can't be found in nature, just that if they are found they are part of a decay chain from a longer lived radioactive element. For example, uranium (U-238) with a half life of 4 billion years, decays into an isotope of thorium (Th-234) with a half life of just a few days, which in turn decays into other elements until eventually a stable isotope of lead (Pb-206) is reached. So in a large deposit of uranium there will be various amounts of short-lived isotopes, which are constantly decaying and being replenished from the uranium.